# How many nations were under the Assyrian Cedar Tree?

Tags: ezekiel

Who was "the mighty one of the heathens" and who were the heathens and how many tribes were under this tree?

> **Ezekiel 31:11**
>   I have therefore delivered him into the hand of the mighty one of the heathen; he shall surely deal with him: I have driven him out for his wickedness.

Answer (score 1):

Ezekiel chapter 31 is addressed to Pharaoh, King of Egypt and to his hordes.  It follows the prophecies in chapters 29 and 30 which describe how the Lord God would send Nebuchadnezzar, King of Babylon, and his armies (the most ruthless of nations) to destroy Egypt.

The fifth oracle, against Egypt, begins with a reminder of what happened to the might power of Assyria, which is compared to a mighty cedar tree.  My New International Version Study Bible makes these comments:

> Assyria – A great nation that had fallen.  In 609 B.C. Pharaoh Neco went to Carchemish to help the Assyrian empire, which was reeling from Babylonian attacks.  The effort failed and Assyria passed from history.
>
> Once a Cedar – The beginning of another allegory.  Lebanon – Known for its cedars.  Water – The Tigris and Euphrates
>
> The Ruler of the Nations – Probably Nabopolassar; or possibly Nebuchadnezzar

This is not a literal tree but an allegorical reference to those pagan and prideful nations who are God’s enemies.  Even though Assyria and Egypt considered themselves to be invincible, God would bring them down.

> This is Pharaoh, and all his hordes, declares the Sovereign Lord (Ezekiel 31:18)

It is also worth remembering that other prophecies were made against Ammon, Moab, Edom, Philistia, Tyre and Sidon (Ezekiel chapters 25, 26, 27 and 28). All of those mighty nations came under the judgment of God, hostile and pagan powers known for their cruel attacks against God’s people

Comment: If this tree was an Allegorical tree then why does it say that the Trees that in the garden of eden Envied this tree. This tree was in fact in Eden, But just not in the Garden of eden. 2 seperate locations. It also states that this tree was in what is now Lebanon. The Mountain in Lebanon is Actually a petrified Stump. It was there and the Trees that were in this Garden had Envied it.

Comment: Interesting, but not something I am able to comment on without doing further research.